# Chrome and media keys

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, media-buttons

I have a Ubuntu setup on a MacBook Pro configured with i3wm. I have just figured out how to make my media keys work with apps like Spotify and VLC, but I cannot make them work with Chrome. More specifically I would like to be able to use Google Play Music with my media keys. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't been able to get media keys working properly in Chrome, but I have a workaround for Google Play Music.

You can download [Google Play Music Desktop Player](https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/) and [playerctl](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl/releases) (both of which have `*.deb` packages).

Install both packages with `dpkg` or the graphical installer that ships with Ubuntu.

Then in your `~/.config/i3/config` file, add the following bindings:

```
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioPause exec playerctl pause
```

**Additional info if you're curious**

playerctl only works for players that implement the MPRIS D-Bus Interface Specification, which Chrome doesn't. There is, however, a feature request to support the specification that you can view here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=267590

At the time of writing it's been closed as `Won't Fix` due to inactivity. There is talk in the comments of re-opening, but I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you. :)

Comment: I didn't have to the bindsym stuff anymore. I did install playerctl